# Where to find GitHub project boards I have been added to as collaborator?

Tags: github, github-projects

I have created a project board on Github and added another user as a collaborator to this private project. He can't find the project under his own project list but only if I give him the direct link.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the permission granted for that user for the project, [using the GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects#get-project-permission-for-a-user)

But I suspect that, unless your project is an [organization project](https://github.com/collab-uniba/socialcde4eclipse/wiki/How-to-setup-a-GitHub-organization,-project-and-team) (where you can [add a collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects#add-project-collaborator)), a collaborator would not see a private project in their own project list unless given a direct link.